# Is there way in karate to get the assertion status like pass or fail in variable for further processing in java?

Tags: karate

In feature file i am writing assertion as

```
match response contains {token_type: '#string' }
```

Is there a way to get the output status of the above assertion value like true or false,
so that i can extend that into java for further processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of Karate is to avoid Java, and I don't recommend doing anything else.

But since you insist, if you want to get the equivalent of the above, just do something like this. Yes, you have to use "normal" JS fundas.

```
* def response = { token_type: 'foo' }
* def isString = typeof(response.token_type) === "string"
* match isString == true
```